# What's a good backup system to use on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, snapshot, archive

I'm running an internal network LAMP server on ubuntu 10.10. I have another ubuntu running on an older ppc g5 with a 640gb drive in it. I'd like to run some software on that G5 that does some snapshot and archiving over the network of the data running on my lamp server.

Ideally i'd like something that has a simple admin gui that allows me to browse and restore files.

What would be a good piece of software?

Thanks

Jason

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12249/ubuntu-backup-solution-to-backup-a-networked-mounted-drive-to-the-local-disk-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) is what you are looking for—it gives all the functionality of Apple's Time Machine on Linux systems, except for the GUI for browsing.  It creates snapshot backups using the power of hard links & rsync(1) so that it only has to copy newly created or changed files.

While rsnapshot doesn't provide any facility for viewing the backups, it stores them as normal directories, so you can view them in any file manager.  The backups folder for my system looks like this:

```
caligula:/mnt/backup/rsnapshot$ ls -lt
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-11-09 05:51 daily.0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-11-08 05:51 daily.1
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-11-07 05:50 daily.2
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-11-06 05:51 daily.3
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-11-05 05:51 daily.4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-11-04 05:51 daily.5
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-11-03 05:51 daily.6
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-10-31 05:50 weekly.0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-10-24 05:50 weekly.1
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-10-17 05:50 weekly.2
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-10-10 05:50 weekly.3
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2010-10-03 08:50 monthly.0
```

Comment: is rsnapshot easy to setup?

Answer (score 0):

I am using [backuppc](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) as a backup/restore application. It has a good web interface that is easy to use. You can define the hosts and then define the directories on each one.

It can run on any Linux distribution not just ubuntu.

Comment: I'm using backuppc. I actually find it quite hard to use to be honest. I'm trying rsync and i was trying to change the directory it saves to but it seems a bit difficult. I'm a novice though so i'm sure anyone with a bit of experience could do it easily.